# Run docker containers on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

Currently I have a Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V. I have a cupule of VMs. One are running Ubuntu with Docker CE and a Nginx container. This is a nested virtualization.

Is it a way to move the Nginx application up a level, and run Docker CE on the Windows Server host? Or is it just possible to run Windows containers at the host? Have seen some old info about Docker EE can run Linux, but have not found a clear information. Also, mySQL seems to be ok, but it can run natively on Windows...

Comment: Does reading https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/ help? In addition, containerization is not virtualization so this is not nested virtualization.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have been reading the docs there. But I was confused. Docker for Windows cannot be run at Windows Server as I understand. As I understand it, running Docker in a Linux VM (under Hyper-V) are considered as nested virtualization, or am I missing the point here?
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#running-docker-desktop-in-nested-virtualization-scenarios

Comment: Running docker on a windows VM is nested virtualization because docker on windows actually runs in a lightweight VM itself. Running docker on a Linux VM, it uses cgroups instead and so it is not nested virtualization.

Comment: Ah, now I understand about the nested/not nested virtualization! But Linux container on a Windows Server host doesn't seems to be supported in "production". My "production" are just home-server, but I try to use supported setup to make my life easier, and paying for Docker EE is not worth for my home-server.